# Replacing both text content and an attribute using MarkLogic's patch functionality

Tags: marklogic

I'm trying to use Marklogic 8's partial update (patch) functionality to change both an attribute of an element and the element's text content in the same request.

If I have a document like this:

```
<root>
    <foo a1="1" a2="2" a3="3" a4="4">text content</foo>
</root>
```

And I try to update it using:

```
<rapi:patch xmlns:rapi="http://marklogic.com/rest-api">
    <rapi:replace select="/root/foo">replace text</rapi:replace>
    <rapi:replace select="/root/foo/@a3">replace a3</rapi:replace>
</rapi:patch>
```

I get `XDMP-CONFLICTINGUPDATES`. The documentation mentions that 'The selected node cannot be the target of any other operation in the patch. The ancestor of the selected node may not be modified by a delete, replace, or replace-insert operation in the same patch.' I'm guessing I'm running into that here, since I'm selecting the element and not the text node directly.

Using xquery, I can specify a text node for replacement like this:

```
xdmp:node-replace(fn:doc($uri)/root/foo/text() , text{ "new text" } )
```

However, I don't seem to be able to do this with patch. Using `/root/foo/text()` results in an error about invalid paths, because patch requires path expressions that can be used to define an index.

Is there a way to change both of these values in the same request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since (as you noted) you can't refer specifically to the text element, I think you'll need to replace the whole element:

```
<rapi:patch xmlns:rapi="http://marklogic.com/rest-api">
  <rapi:replace select="/root/foo">
    <foo a1="1" a2="2" a3="new 3" a4="4">new text</foo>
  </rapi:replace>
</rapi:patch>
```

The element is a parent of the attribute, so there's no way to escape the conflicting update.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Worth a shot... Thanks!